# Add a textview for header and footer

Tags: android, xml, layout, gridview, textview

I've a pretty noob issue with LinearLayouts and GridView.
I want to display an activity with and header, a GridView that scrolls and a footer.
I search how to do this stuff but i'm stuck to get the footer appearing.
I've this xml for the activity layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MyActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_text"
        android:text="Header!"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/my_grid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dip"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dip" >
    </GridView>
       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/footer_text"
        android:text="Footer!"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

but with this layout only the header appears. Where i'm wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead if this android:layout_height="wrap_content" use android:layout_height="200dp" for gridview. use a desired value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the height of your `GridView` is set to `wrap_content`. This means that if you have more content, the `GridView` will continue to expand downwards, pushing your footer off the screen. Instead, set the height of your `GridView` to `0dp` and then set `android:layout_weight` to `1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Header!"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/my_grid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lll"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dip"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dip" >
</GridView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/footer_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Footer!"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```